# Best practices for displaying a Model Property in View depending on another Property

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an MVC 4 application in ASP.NET 4.0. In my View I am displaying the Properties of a Model; one Property in particular may need to be hyperlink with a tooltip depending on another Property in the Model.

It's easier to explain by showing the code in the View:

```
@if (Model.HasMultipleErrorReasons)
{
   <td data-toggle="tooltip" title="@Model.AllErrors"><a href="#">Multiple</a></td>
}
else
{
   <td>@Model.Error</td>
}
```

I know there is nothing wrong with this and that it is functional, but I would prefer to not have to write out the `<td></td>` twice; the example above is very stripped down and in practice it is much messier.

Is there a way to avoid this or a better way to do it?

Comment: could you use a difference view? or 2 (or more)  partial views? If there is a lot of if/else statements, I think that might be the best...

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of the breaks of the game when working with templated rendering engines. You could abstract the code in some way so you don't have to see it, either using a partial view or a `HtmlHelper` extension. However, there's slight but not insignificant performance cost to using partial views, so if you end up with a ton of different partial views being rendered on the same page for multiple things like this, you'll feel it. This is also probably overkill for an extension. Although, if you can boil the code down enough that it would be applicable to a wide range of uses, it might warrant creating an extension method.

Overall, I would say just keep it as you have it.